# NestJS Firebase C

Tags: firebase, nestjs

I am integrating Nestjs with firebase admin, the controller is not updating the view. With the service there is not problem, update in real time.

Someone will have some suggestion, what is my wrong in the code?

**The Service that inject the controller is:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';


export interface Customer {
 direction: string,
 codLegal: string,
 phone: string,
 name: string
}

export interface CustomerId extends Customer{
  id: string;
}


@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

constructor() {}

findCustomers(): Promise<any>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        admin.firestore().collection('/data/LYvBew5FDpjLqcQjA2Ra/info')
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const promises: any = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
            promises.push({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data() as Customer,
            });
        });
        console.log(promises);
        resolve(promises);          
        })
    });
 }

}
```

**The basic controller is: **

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

import { CustomerService } from './services/customer.service';

@Controller('customers') export class CustomerController {

constructor(private readonly customerService: CustomerService) {

}

@Get()
async findAll() {
    try {
        return await this.customerService.findCustomers();
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking in terms of HTTP, the controller will not update the view. The view is rendered once you call the findAll route and send to the client.

If you want to show updates to the view in realtime, you should include firebase into your frontend.

Comment: thanks for respond, I'm new in nodejs but I'm angular developer, I want integrate angular and nestjs with firebase but, I should put firebase in the front(angularfire2) and backend(firebase)?

Comment: @parmalat22 correct, your findCustomers method just forwards to firestore, so instead you can use firestore in the frontend using angularfire2.